# “Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)”?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my swift code
i will get above error on this line : `guard (newUser["status"] as! Int != 0)`

```
@IBAction func signInButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if validator(){
        DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async(execute: {

            let datas:[String:String] = ["email":self.emailField.text!,"name": self.nameField.text!,"password" : self.passwordField.text!]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SwiftSpinner.show("Signin' in...")
            }
            let newUser:NSDictionary = self.marketcloud!.createUser(datas)
            print(newUser)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
                guard (newUser["status"] as! Int != 0) else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Email already in use. Try with a different one!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close",
                        style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive,
                        handler: nil))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Ok!", message: "User created successfully!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
                    UserData.setLastRegisteredUser(self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!);
                    print("Setted UserData \n \(UserData.getLastRegistedUserEmail(),UserData.getLastRegisteredUserPassword())")
                    //returns to the login view
                    let next = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
                    next.downloadProducts = false
                    next.load = true                        
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
                }));
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why you tagged this as JavaScript - I've edited the question to use the Swift tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand how `guard` works.

The condition must be an optional binding with `let` or a boolean expression

```
guard let status = newUser["status"] as? Int, status != 0 else { ...
```

And no parentheses in Swift.